# How do I iterate over an object literal array to find a matching property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is a shopping cart.

I would like to retrieve the prices of items in regularListings and use them to calculate the total of my cart.

The first item in the cart 'michael' is the name of the customer.

How can this be done in JavaScript?

```
'use strict'

const listing =
  (name, price) => ({
    name,
    price
  })

const cart =
  (customer, ...items) => ({
    customer,
    items
  })

const listedPrice =
  listing =>
    name =>
      name === listing.name
        ? listing.price
        : 0

const regularListings = [
  listing('detergent', 10),
  listing('hennessey', 100),
  listing('carlo rozzi', 20),
  listing('coffee', 5),
  listing('cookies', 6),
  listing('mountain dew', 2)
]

const carts = [
  cart(
    'michael',
    'coffee',
    'hennessey',
    'coffee',
    'hennessey',
    'coffee',
    'hennessey'
  )
]
```

Comment: You're going to run into a problem: object properties have no guaranteed ordering. Your cart should probably be an array, not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce `regularListings` and calculate the totals

```
const regularListings = [
  listing('detergent', 10),
  listing('hennessey', 100),
  listing('carlo rozzi', 20),
  listing('coffee', 5),
  listing('cookies', 6),
  listing('mountain dew', 2)
]

const total = regularListings.reduce((state, item) => state + item, 0);
```

Comment: If you'd like to use ES6 arrow notation: `regularListings.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0);`

Comment: Also, the 0 is there because that is the value `total` will start at, in case that wasn't clear.